# Gradle flatDir path to module

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android project divided into two modules: app (main application) and mylibrary. I have an myaarfile.aar file that I want to add to mylibrary. I work on MacOSX (not sure if that's important).

In mylibrary `gradle` file I have specified:

```
compile(name:'myaarfile', ext:'aar')
```

and in global gradle file I've put this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'file:/Users/myuser/myproject/mylibrary/libs'
        }
    }
}
```

and it works fine. But there's an obvious issue with this path and I'd like to make it universal. But changing it to:

```
dirs '${rootDir}/libs'
```

didn't work, cause gradle was looking for the aar in:

> file:/Users/myuser/myproject/mylibrary/${rootDir}/libs/myaarfile.aar

changing the path to:

```
dirs '/libs'
```

didn't work either, cause gradle was looking for aar in:

> file:/libs/myaarfile.aar

How should I specify the path so gradle would search for the aar in correct folder? Unfortunately I can't use another method to add the aar.

**EDIT:**

Found it!

```
flatDir {
    dirs "${project(':mylibrary').projectDir}/libs"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

```
flatDir {
    dirs "${project(':mylibrary').projectDir}/libs"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`dirs 'libs'`

That works in this project:

https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/usf-step-sensor-demo/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: That worked but only if I put the aar into main module (app/libs folder). If it's in mylibrary/libs I had to use the path from the 'EDIT'.

Comment: Gotcha!  Go ahead and put your EDIT answer into a real answer below, if that solved it.  It's ok to answer your own questions, you'll just need to wait a few days until you can officially mark it as the answer.